# Can a spaceship land on a strongly magnetic planet?

Tags: spaceships, electromagnetism

What would happen to a spaceship if it tried to land on a planet that had a magnetic field as strong as Jupiter's?

Comment: Hi Prof! This question is really not appropriate for this forum -- this forum is focused on worldbuilding. Check out the [help] and [tour] for more information. Maybe space exploration: https://space.stackexchange.com Am voting to close this question as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Its electronic systems might malfunction if not shielded properly. But traveling through space typically requires shielding.

Magnetism will also pull the ship towards nearest pole and down (if near the pole). The strength of the effect will depend on amount of iron or steel in the ship; other metals are not magnetic, aluminum, titanuim, etc. Even with full steel ship, I am not sure if magnetic force will add much to gravity and wind.